# Problem with editing message in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, edit

I'm having an issue with editing bot's messages in discord.py
This is the code i'm using:

```
if message.content.startswith('!edit'):
  await message.channel.send('Message')
  time.sleep(2)
  await message.edit(content='Edited')
```

And I'm getting this error:
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50005): Cannot edit a message authored by another user

If i understand correctly, the bot tries to edit the command message (!edit) sent by me and not it's own one. Is there a way to make the bot target it's own message or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure it is indeed its own message. However, giving the modifying message permission to your bot could be a work around until you find a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the message sent by the bot, then you can edit it.

Also you better use `asyncio` and not only `sleep`, that's not really new anymore.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
import asnycio

if message.content.startswith('!edit'):
    test = await message.channel.send('Message') # Defined message
    await asyncio.sleep(2) # Wait 2 seconds
    await test.edit(content='Edited') # Edit it
```